# How to write two version of native dlls which can coexist side by side?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

I need to write dlls which can be coexisted in the windows. I heard there is technology called Sxs, how to get started with it?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx

Comment: Are you trying to use both in the same process?  Either way, the best solution is also the simplest: Give each a different name.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start would be Wikipedia:

[Wikipedia: Side-by-side assemblies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-by-side_assembly)

Also:

[WinSxS: How to take dependency on specific version of gdiplus.dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381028/winsxs-how-to-take-dependency-on-specific-version-of-gdiplus-dll)

There are lots of examples that can be found.

If you have specific issues, that's another matter...

Answer (score 0):

A practical view of this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/88363/Retrieve-the-Assembly-Identities-from-a-Manifest-u